# Why does not bootstrap work in my Meteor project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, meteor

My containers with bootstrap do not work, my component is not shown as in the example

[getbootstrap.com/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/grid) , when I try to add add the package it says that it has already been installed but it does not work once underway

my **component.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class SideBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
            var estilo = { textDecoration: "underline" };
            return (
                <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

            );
    };
}
export default SideBar;
```

and my **json**

```
  {
  "name": "bonafont_2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "antd": "^2.13.10",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "indexof": "0.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "pui-react-dropdowns": "^8.3.3",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.1.11",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-popover": "^0.5.4",
    "react-responsive": "^4.0.3",
    "react-reveal": "^0.7.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.6.7",
    "react-simple-parallax": "^0.2.6",
    "react-slick": "^0.16.0",
    "react-springy-parallax": "^1.0.11",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "scroll-progress-react": "^0.1.4",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.76.0",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.3.2",
    "simple-schema": "^1.1.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

can you help me ?

Comment: What's the issue exactly, the classes aren't getting applied? Issues including it somewhere? How are you including it? Do you include bootstrap CSS file in your HTML (or somewhere else)? You have react-bootstrap module, but you're not actually using any of those components in your component. Is that the bootstrap stuff you're referring to? Please clarify. Also, the link in your post 404's

Comment: you could review the last comment @Jayce444

Answer (score 1):

Simply add bootstrap to your project, and styles will be applied accordingly.

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```